# jQuery toggle: Hide the first div, show the other div

Tags: jquery, toggle

What I want is the following: I'm making a website, and I want to put some text on the top of the page and a button in the middle of the page. If the user clicks on it, the content above the button (say Div A) hides and the content underneath it (say Div B), which is hidden, will show and the button disappears. What kind of jQuery code do I need for that?

Comment: Could you provide the HTML code for you page?

Comment: Everything you need to know is right here: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited due to points in comments:

```
<div id="divA">
    Contents
    <input type="button" onclick="$('#divA').hide();$('#divB').show();" />
</div>
<div id="divB">
    More Contents.
</div>
```

And of course, style `#divB` to be `display: hidden;`

Comment: I don't think you got your selectors right. What would be the HTML for that?

Comment: The described 'div A' would be `<div class='A'>`, and the same respectively for div B. This presumes that it's just using class selectors for specific styling instead of IDs.

Comment: You should post the HTML as well, since your selector will only work if A is the class, not the ID

Comment: And what about the disappearing button?

Comment: Either didn't spot that in the original post or it was edited in after I posted mine. Edited post to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I have forgotten the button. Here is the modified code.

You create a *hidden* class and then play with the method *toggleClass*.

CSS:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

JS:

```
$("#myButton").click(function() {
  $("#divA, #divB").toggleClass("hidden");
  $(this).addClass("hidden");
});
```

Here, the *this* keyword will refer to the button you are clicking on.

Comment: Of course, you will add the *hidden* class on the second div at page initialization. ;)

Comment: What about the disappearing button?

Comment: I had modified the above code to take care of your button I had completely forgotten.